# ASP.NET 4 MVC Web API Key Value / List Collection á la JSON for XML

Tags: xml, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a generic key/value-collection class which can be serialized into xml and json?

I dont want to use model-classes as return value. (I do not need classes because I dont have .NET on client-side and don't want class implementations. Using interfaces and classes is problematic anyway.)

There are JSON-Classes (e.g. JSON.NET) but this objects can only be serialized to JSON.
I need a neutral class which can both.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not need classes because I dont have .NET on client-side and
>   don't want class implementations

That's exactly what interoperable formats such as XML and JSON are meant for :-) To translate your .NET specific classes into an interoperable exchange format so that any XML/JSON enable client could understand. So yeah, look no more, go ahead and define your view models and have your API methods return those custom view models. Or collections of them.

Other than that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` should work with both formats.

Comment: Using classes is ok, but in my case I have dynamic content and I want to send lists/arrays and key-value-collections. I can use List<T> and Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, but it I want an list with dictionaries as entries, the xml-serialization will fail. (but json will succeed). Maybe I only support json as content-type... :P